# ZSH shell on Ubuntu WSL can't find node, npm, nvm or any other installations after PATH adjustment

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I installed Ubuntu using WSL2 on Windows 11 and configured oh-my-zsh as my default shell. After that, I created /etc/wsl.conf and added the following lines:

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=false
```

to not include the Windows PATH in WSL. Now, my zsh shell can't pick any installation like node, npm or vscode. It must be because of some config edit I need to make in ~/.zshrc configuration file. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't pick any installation" .. do you mean you already installed it and its not finding it when you type it in the shell?

Comment: It says `zsh: command not found: npm` even when npm is installed. same for node, nvm and vscode.

Answer (score 2):

Add these few lines in the .zshrc file:

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_comp$
```